# rounded controlgroup not working in an accordion

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I use controlgroup in collapsible accordion... The first opened accordion work well and the corner are runded for controlgroup..

But when I open an other one, controlgroup aren't collapsible anymore..

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
  active: 0,
  heightStyle: "content",
  collapsible: true
});
$("input:radio, input:checkbox").checkboxradio({
  icon: false
});
$(".controle").controlgroup();
```

I have created a test here : ​https://jsfiddle.net/scfmwakk/1/

You can check that this is not working well

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is due to the order of operations.

Forked Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mcc7eoch/

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $(".controle").controlgroup();
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    active: 0,
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true
  });
  $("input:radio, input:checkbox").checkboxradio({
    icon: false
  });
});
```

This allows each control group to be rendered first and then placed in the accordian.

Comment: No finally I tried in real condition and this is really not working... I don't know how to fix that...

Comment: Need more info as it is working in my fiddle. Can you update your post with more info or a better example?

Comment: No really strange problem in my code.. this is only in a page now that I have a trouble.. don't understand why...

Comment: @Chatis okay. Not sure how I can assist. Maybe the CSS is not loading?

Comment: no because the CSS is loading, but not in the right solution... You can test by yourself here : [link](http://demo.plugin.ch/admin)